# How many possibilities are there for the birthday months of five people?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Question: How many possibilities are there for the birthday months of five people?

Well, I tried to do this: $364$ because a birthday have day and month, but I don't know if it is good.

$$\frac{364!}{(364 - 5)!}$$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I do not understand your calculation.  There are $365$ days in a year that is not a leap year.  However, we are only interested in the months when a person's birthday might occur.  There are only $12$ possible months for each of the five people.  By the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), there are $12^5$ possible distributions of birthday months for five people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each person has only one of 12 possibilities. There are 5 people. The way I like to think of this is a 5-tuple from the set of possibilities. (Jan, Jan, Jan, Jan, Jan) or (Jan, Jan, Jan, Jan, Feb), and so on. Thus, there are $12^5$ possibilities.

Comment: and how can i do with the permute metodology?

Comment: @pipe123xwe: It’s not a problem that involves permutations.